# Third-Party Java Script Form

Tags: javascript, blackbaud

I am running a form from a third-party. The content is at: https://safefuturesct.org/donatenow/
My donation button has somehow become a hidden hover button at the top of the page. Any suggestions on how I can get the donation button back under the form showing permanently?

```
<div id="bbox-root">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.bboxInit = function ()
{
   bbox.showForm('ed52b736-7342-4bc3-a24d-8d669eb3d316');
};
(function () {
   var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
   e.src = 'https://bbox.blackbaudhosting.com/webforms/bbox-min.js';
   document.querySelector('head').appendChild(e);
} ());
</script>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page is including some CSS at this URL:

https://safefuturesct.org/wp-content/themes/psychologycare/style.css

One of the rules is:

```
input[type="submit"]{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    border: 1px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

The `opacity: 0` makes your button completely see-through, and it also contains the positioning rules that are making it appear on the top.

This rule is what's making the hover make it show up, from a different CSS file:

```
.BBFormContainer[data-bbox-part-id="ed52b736-7342-4bc3-a24d-8d669eb3d316"] .BBFormSubmitbutton:hover {
    opacity: .85;
}
```

The best way to debug what is causing certain styles to show up is to use your developer tools and look at the computed styles; that will point you to what the *effective* styles are for an element and where the rules live that are applying those styles.

To make the button not be transparent, you'll have to either edit, remove, or override the styles.

**Update**

You could try something like this to your CSS to override the offending styles. It's hard to verify/test since this is CSS and there could be lots of things affecting your styles:

```
input.BBFormSubmitbutton[type="submit"] {
    position: static;
    left: auto;
    top: auto;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jacob. Is there code for me to override it on this page only?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was successfully able to adjust the parent style and have fixed the problem!